# how to use distinct in sqlite and cursor without _id essential column?

Tags: android, sqlite, distinct

I have an table that i should use this query for right answer:

```
select distinct IDPAGE,TIT from contents where NUM=1;
```

and send this cursor to cursorAdapter. As you know, in this cursor should be an _id column. if not, app not started. but i just want distinct my tables and not _id col. i want a query like:

```
select rowid _id distinct IDPAGE,TIT from contents where NUM=1;
```

in sql , i can use DENSE_RANK() but not in sqlite. please help me...

Comment: `select distinct IDPAGE as _id,TIT from contents where NUM=1;` ?

Comment: @pskink , ow my god. I thought that _id should be unique. but is not essential. my problem is SOLVED. THANK YOU...

Comment: in general _id should be unique, otherwise it is more difficult to access your db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android framework requires a unique `_id` column in some cursors, but this column must be unique only in this particular result set.
So if you have a column that is unique in the results you're selecting, you can use it also as the `_id` column:

```
SELECT IDPAGE AS _id, IDPAGE, TIT FROM ... WHERE ...;
```

(The DISTINCT is then not needed because a unique column never has duplicates.)

If you do not have a single unique column, you must also get the `rowid` (or whatever your INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is named) from the table. To still get distinct values for the other columns, you have to replace DISTINCT with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT MIN(rowid) AS _id, IDPAGE, TIT
FROM contents
WHERE NUM = 1
GROUP BY IDPAGE, TIT;
```

Comment: I love it. great answer.